# How can I use the Scala REPL to test java code - java and scala REPL giving different outputs

Tags: java, scala, casting

I am trying to use the REPL for testing my java code. I had set my class path and launched the REPL and I could access my application classes inside REPL.

I launched a method which makes a webservice call and it is throwing a java.lang.ClassCastException. I wrote a java program which does the same thing as the series of commands entered in the REPL and ran it with the same classpath, it is running without issues and giving the result.

Any clues on why it is not running under scala?
Does the rules of casting is strict in scala?, and if I am using an API on which I have no control how can I tell Scala to be behave like java so, that I can test my methods which makes a lot of API calls and code written by others.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.webservice.encoding.ImageCodec cannot be cast to weblogic.xml.schema.binding.Serializer
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping.addOptionalEntries(XSDTypeMapping.java:762)
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping.createOptionalMapping(XSDTypeMapping.java:665)
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping.createPrimaryMapping(XSDTypeMapping.java:655)
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping.createInstance(XSDTypeMapping.java:138)
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping.<clinit>(XSDTypeMapping.java:118)
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.TypeMappingFactoryBase.createDefaultMapping(TypeMappingFactoryBase.java:18)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.encoding.DefaultRegistry.<init>(DefaultRegistry.java:110)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.encoding.DefaultRegistry.<init>(DefaultRegistry.java:37)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:91)
```

Since many are asking for the source code to answer this, here is the snippet I entered in the scala REPL. It makes API calls which are copyrighted and cannot be shared here, I can answer to questions to provide more info on this issue without violating the norms.

```
val clientManager=new ClientManager()
val client=clientManager.getClient(<clientId>)
/*client location is stored in another system which exposes its data as a webservice.
 We use weblogic tools to compile the WSDL to create client (Web service client, not to
 be confused with the client object which represent a customer) to access the system
 hosting the data*/
val res=client.getLocation //exception is thrown at this line where a web-service call is made
```

I did something different and I got a completely different exception this time
instead of using `val res=client.getLocation` I used `client.getLocation` without assigning it to a variable and this time the exception thrown is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.XSDTypeMapping
        at weblogic.xml.schema.binding.internal.TypeMappingFactoryBase.createDefaultMapping(TypeMappingFactoryBase.java:18)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.encoding.DefaultRegistry.<init>(DefaultRegistry.java:110)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.encoding.DefaultRegistry.<init>(DefaultRegistry.java:37)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:91)
```

I ran the interpreted with the `-nobootcp` option and it ran without throwing any exception which are above but the result I got is null in both the cases

Anyone using Scala REPL to test client written from stubs generated by weblogic 10.3 and were successful in using it?

Comment: Why this was down voted? I am not finding any valid comments or reason for down voting this. I had verified that I set the classpath and all the settings correctly, I am not sure why I am getting this exception only in Scala REPL. I am new to scala and just trying by putting it to use. Any comments or response will help, please provide some hints on why you think this question is not correct or invalid

Comment: include some code.... stack trace alone is not enough

Comment: hi rana, I could not include the remaining code since they are copyrighted and they are our client specific API. I guess there is enough info in the stack trace. we are trying to cast - weblogic.webservice.encoding.ImageCodec to weblogic.xml.schema.binding.Serializer which is not allowed. But the same API calls when called from a java main method with the same classpath doesn't produce this class cast exception. The package weblogic.* are part of weblogic API and we have included them in our classpath.

Comment: It is the JVM who does the casting. My best guess is that some custom class loader is being used with Java.

Comment: I am not using any custom class loader with java. I just wrote a main method that includes the same set of commands that I entered in the Scala REPL and executed it. Anyway I will check the class loading to see if there are issues.

Comment: can you try running the same scala code without REPL?

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace has nothing to do with Scala.  The exception is happening deep in some weblogic code.  Why do you think Scala is causing the problem?  The most likely cause is a mismatch in library, e.g. you're using a different class path in your Scala test than in your Java test.

Still, I'll try to answer your implicit question: for reference types that can be expressed equivalently in both Java and Scala, Scala's rules for casting are the same as Java's.

Comment: I am using the same classpath for both scala and java. I have exported the CLASSPATH variable in a shell and using both scala and java from the same shell. I will try to check if there is any issues with my classpath settings.

Comment: Tested with -nobootcp option, it runs without errors, but gives null as result. If client.getLocation is used without assigning it to a variable instead of val res=client.getLocation a different exception is thrown. I have updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's really hard to tell what's going on.  However... since you mentioned that you are starting a web service I'm guessing you are using Scala remote actors.

Before you `start` the actor try doing `classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Comment: I have not written much in Scala. I can give the code here but it contains many API calls and I cannot give all those API here.

Comment: @tutysara - sorry but I don't think that will suffice.  If you can't provide the code that is causing the problem then you're probably on your own.  One of the perils of proprietary software, I'm afraid.